# Fetch data from local Json server in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, json-server

My Local Json Server data is something like this: [image: Json]

I used it in server:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const Server = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/office',
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {'accept': 'application/json'}
});
export default Server;
```

But I'm unable to fetch it, I need help in fetching it from local json server.

```
export function fetchJobs(props) {
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch({type: JobsTypes.FETCH_OFFICE});
    Server
    .get('/office')
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({type: JobsTypes.FETCH_OFFICE_SUCCESSFUL,payload:response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({type:JobsTypes.FETCH_OFFICE_FAILED,payload:err});
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to change   `baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'`

Comment: @PritishVaidya Tried it, still the same. Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get? Also try to log the error and response.

Comment: There is no error in it, the page is just blank and in network response there is no localhost 3000

Comment: You are trying using debug mode right?

Comment: Yes remote debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using Android Virtual Device?

Localhost is going to be: `10.0.2.2`
So in your case you have to use: `'http://10.0.2.2:3000'`

Let me know if this works for you.

Ok, just to clarify for anyone else who gets to this answer with the same question:

If you're using `Android Virtual Device` on your dev machine THEN you need to use `http://10.0.2.2:<port>` in order to communicate with your dev server running on `http://localhost:<port>`

If you're using a physical device, make sure it is in the same network as your dev machine and replace the `10.0.2.2` part with your dev machines ip.

Comment: Yes, I have connected to my mobile via USB debugging.Still the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Changed localhost to my computer IP and it worked fine, thank you

Answer (score -1):

I beleive you need to change  your URL: 'http://localhost:3000'